# Solution-Verification：Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+k}}\right)^n$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

[Here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/628602179/answer/3272412547) is a proof posted in a Chinese website.

Since $f_n(x):=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+x}}$ is convex on $x\in(0,+\infty),$ by **discrete Hadamard inequality**, it holds that $$f_n\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\le\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf_n(k)\le \frac{f_n(n)+f_n(1)}{2}.\\$$
Therefore $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{n+1}{2}}}\le\sum_{k=1}^nf_n(k)\le \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{n}{2}}},$$
which implies $$\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{n+1}{2}}}\right)^n\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf_n(k)\right)^n\le \left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{n}{2}}}\right)^n.$$

The limits of both sides are $e^{-3/4}$ as $n \to \infty$. By the squeezing theorem, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf_n(k)\right)^n=e^{-3/4}.$$

**This solution is likely to be elegant, but I wonder whether it is correct or not. What is discrete Hadamard inequality?**

Comment: That discrete version of Hermit-Hadamard is certainly not true in full generality - take $n = 4$ and it asserts $f(x_2) + f(x_3)\leq f(x_1) + f(x_4)$ for a convex $f$ and $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4.$ This is obviously not true in general and so the fact that your $f_n$ has a very specific form is probably important. When you do the simple Riemann sum estimate, you get a weaker:
$$f(\frac{n+1}{2})\leq\dfrac{f(1) + \ldots +f(n-1)}{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The solution seems correct, although I have no idea how to obtain the second inequality from the "discrete Hadamard inequality". This amounts to proving

$$\frac{f_n(1) + f_n(n)}{2} \leq f_n(n/2),$$

which I believe is not so trivial.

And the "discrete [Hermit-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality)", as claimed in the solution, can be formulated and proved as follows:

> **Theorem.** Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex. Then for $n \geq 2$, we have
> $$ f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n-1}k\right) \leq \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2}. $$

*Proof.* The first part follows from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n-1}k\right)
\geq f\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(a + \frac{b-a}{n-1}k \right) \right) = f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right). $$

For the second inequality, the convexity of $f(x)$ implies that the graph of $f(x)$ lies below the line segment $\ell$ joining $(a, f(a))$ to $(b, f(b))$, that is,

$$ f(x) \leq \ell(x) := f(a) + \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}(x - a). $$

Then it follows that

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n-1}k\right)
\leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \ell\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n-1}k\right)
= \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2}. $$

---

**Addendum.** Just for reference, below is a statement that generalizes both the continuous and discrete version of Hermit-Hadamard inequality, which can be proved in an almost identical manner as above.

> **Theorem.** Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex, and let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $[a, b]$. Also, define $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ by the relation
> $$ \int_{[a, b]} x \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \lambda a + (1-\lambda) b.$$
> Then it follows that
> $$ f(\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b) \leq \int_{[a,b]} f(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \leq \lambda f(a) + (1-\lambda) f(b). $$

Comment: $\frac{f_n(1) + f_n(n)}{2} \leq f_n(n/2)$ holds by $AM-QM$.

Comment: I think the RHS can be proved using Karamata and its relaxation when $f$ is a decreasing function.

Answer (score 1):

*For the pleasure of using algebra only and to obtain more than the limit itself.*

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+k}}=\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n^2+n+1\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2},(n+1)^2\right)$$

For large $n$

$$S_n=1-\frac{3}{4 n}+\frac{5}{8 n^2}-\frac{39}{64 n^3}+\frac{85}{128
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$\log(S_n)=-\frac{3}{4 n}+\frac{11}{32 n^2}-\frac{9}{32 n^3}+\frac{291}{1024 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$n\log(S_n)=-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{11}{32 n}-\frac{9}{32 n^2}+\frac{291}{1024   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$S_n^n=e^{n\log(S_n)}= \frac{1}{e^{3/4}}\left(1+\frac{11}{32 n}-\frac{455}{2048 n^2}+\frac{38195}{196608
   n^3}+ O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \right)$$ which is in a relative error of $0.10$% for $n>3$ and  $0.01$% for $n>6$.